# Use Vaadin's Valo theme outside of Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, licensing, vaadin-valo-theme

I find the Vaadin's Valo theme so beautiful that I would like to use it without Vaadin. That is, I want to grab only the theme files (*.scss) and use them in an app written in Emberjs.

Does the Vaadin license allows this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the license of Vaadin's Valo theme is the same as the main project (e.g Apache 2.0), the answer is yes, as along as you comply with the license terms that are rather simple.
https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/731fec8cc81c4ff6ca53d404b68a2c1538fd3885/LICENSE